# I lost my GUI after uninstalling Raspberry Pwn

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I wants to make my Pi a network security tool, so I downloaded the source code from Raspberry Pwn's github source [https://github.com/pwnieexpress/Raspberry-Pwn].

I found my network rather slow when installing, so I interrupted the progress. I used its uninstall script to make sure that all changes would be recovered.

The uninstall successfully ended, but since then I cannot proceed on to the GUI after I typed startx. Are there any way for me to proceed a clean install of all GUI components?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg

sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in an attempt to recover the GUI, I mistakenly installed an emulator that is incompatible with Raspbian. After trying your suggested command, startx would still start with that GUI. How can I deal with this? Thanks.

Comment: I think your best option is to start from a fresh Raspbian installation.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I would definite try.